# How to pass argument from activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to pass the address of a web url from pageradapter to my fragment but in that process i am getting a null object reference error.
***This is my pageradapter***

```
public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{

    int tabCount;


    public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int numberOfTabs)
    {
        super(fm);
        this.tabCount = numberOfTabs;

    }


    @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            switch (position)
            {
                case 0:

                    Yahoo tab1 = new Yahoo();
                    Yahoo.newInstance("https://www.yahoo.com");
                    return tab1;

                    default:
                    return null;

            }
 @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return tabCount;
    }
}
```

This is my fragment . I am not sure why can't I get it to work.I tried to put the same thing in onCreate method as well but the error still exists.

```
public class Yahoo extends Fragment {

   private WebView webView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar1;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout1;

    public Yahoo() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

  public static Yahoo newInstance(String webUrl) {
        Yahoo yahoo= new Yahoo();
        //set arguments
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("website", webUrl);
        yahoo.setArguments(args);

        return Yahoo;

    }

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
         return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab, container, false);
 }
  @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //getting error here when calling  back arguments
       final String url = getArguments().getString("website");
       webView.loadUrl(url);


}
```

Comment: I see no problem with your code, can you clarify why it is not working? What errors are you having?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what i can't figure out. In short I have a tablayout with view pager. main activity initializes tabs and pageradapter associates the fragments. The error as marked above is   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: Please add the code of the PageAdapter

Comment: Hi Benjamin, I have already added the pager adapter however I updated the full implementation of the code as per your request. Any help would be appreciated or if you would like for any other code ?

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a new Fragment, not the newInstance.

Try this:

```
case 0:
   return Yahoo.newInstance("https://www.yahoo.com");
```

Comment: Yep, this is the fix, but you were faster than me